# Finding a running background process on computer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a program I would like to monitor if someone has it open or not.  It turns out the program runs in the background like "wowexec.exe". So the processes are indented in under "explorer.exe".  I've tried two things to try and identify if this program is open or not.

My first is

```
 Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Process")
 Dim retValue As Boolean = p.Length > 0

 MsgBox(retValue & vbCrLf & "Process")
```

This works perfect for finding process on the computer, it will identify "explorer.exe" and anything else running, but cannot not identify something running in the backgorund like "wowexec.exe".

My second attempt at this (Which may not be written correctly) is

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lngFindIt As Long
    lngFindIt = FindWindow(vbNullString, "WindowName")
    If lngFindIt = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Does not Exist")
    Else
        MsgBox("Exists!")
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason this always returns "Exists!" regardless what I put in for the Window name. I can type a bunch of letter or leave it blank and it returns "Exists!".

Any help is a big thanks.

Comment: "but cannot not identify something running in the backgorund like "wowexec.exe"" why not?  What is the problem?  Is there some error?

Comment: No error, it just returns false like it doesn't even exist. I'm not sure why either. Another file that appears when my program is launched is a "gsw.exe" which is also indented under "explorer.exe". That also can't be found using my first method.

Comment: I just didn't get the error in the `FindWindow` call either, and found an answer only [here](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?56187-Why-is-the-API-Findwindow-is-always-returning-a-handle!!). It must be `) As IntPtr` instead of `) As Long` in the api declaration.

Comment: @KekuSemau That did the trick! Thanks, I would have never caught that. I can at least Identify now if the program is open.  Anyone have any clue why the process cannot be found? Is it possible it is running through a remote server and that is why it is indented underneath the explorer.exe and cannot be found directly?